# android webview splash screen app not working

Tags: android, web, splash-screen

Hi I am working with android app.I just created a web view with splash screen and a progress bar.Initially splash screen is loaded and then progress bar works,at the same time web URL load in back ground. After completion of loading splash screen not dismissed.so I cant see the web page. how to solve this ???

here is my code

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
       if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
         image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
         progressBar.setMax(100);

            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new wapWebViewClient());
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
              {
                 @Override
                 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                 {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                   //here dismiss your splash
                 }
              });
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
                   {
                   if(progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                   progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                   if(progress == 100) {
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }
                }
            });


         } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "internet is not avialable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
            ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
           ImageButton  imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

         imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


       public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent feedbackEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                feedbackEmail.setType("text/email");
               feedbackEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"prince@gmail.com"});
             feedbackEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(feedbackEmail, "Send Feedback:"));
        }
       });

       imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


       public void onClick(View v) {
              View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null); // inflating popup layout
              mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true); //Creation of popup

                mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);    // Displaying popup
               ImageButton Sub = (ImageButton) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.submit);     
                Sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                  mpopup.dismiss();

            }
        }); 
       }  
       });

           }

        private void incrementPercentage(){
       int mProgressStatus=0;
        mProgressStatus++;//i declared it as a private Integer on the activity class.
      progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
    }



       public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
          ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) 
      {
           NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
           if(netInfos != null)
           if(netInfos.isConnected()) 
            return true;
       }
       return false;
      }

         private class wapWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

      @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
             return true;
          }

      @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      // when the page loaded splash screen has been invisible
      mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      }

       @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        // if any error occured this message will be showed
                 Toast.makeText(WebViewExample.this, "Error is occured, please try again..." + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        }

       @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
      // setting of back button
      mWebView.goBack();
         return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }
       }
```

Comment: When you Navigate webview from splash at that time finish() splash activity. It's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override WebViewClient's method and dismiss splash when the page is loaded

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
      {
         @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
         {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           //here dismiss your splash
         }
      });
```

Comment: Post Your code that we can know what are you doing now :). In your case if you want hine ImageView you have to set its visibility to GONE

Comment: just add `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and `image.setVisibility(View.GONE);` (I suppose that is your splash) in `onPageFinished` method

Comment: already done.but progress bar gone..but still splash image is there

Comment: `image` is your splash?. I see you use `webview.setWebViewClient` two times. Delete the second one

Comment: in method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` just return `false` (don't call `loadUrl`). And add `onPageStarted` method to show again splash and progress when the another page is starting loading

Comment: thank you it works..I have one more doubt  , I used the code mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0); but it shows xml popup at the bottom ..how can it to be overflow the web layout ??

Comment: I don't know how that function works, but I assume you have to change `Gravity.BOTTOM` to `Gravity.CENTER` and as the first parameter use `mWebView`

Answer (score 1):

Use [setWebViewClient()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient%28android.webkit.WebViewClient%29) and override [onPageFinished()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and hide your progress bar or splash on this method.

Comment: now, you just hide your progress bar in onPageFinished() method.

Comment: image.setVisibility(View.GONE); is also there...image is my splash screen image.

Comment: Try to implement only one WebViewClient() and implement onPageFinished() method and add image.setVisibility(View.GONE) and Progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE). that's it.

Comment: I used the code  mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);  but it shows xml popup at the bottom ..how can it to be overflow the web layout ??

Comment: First if my answer useful to you then +1 up and then turn to solve your another issue.

Comment: I have no more reputation please forgive me